# how does one change home directory in ubuntu 13.04

Tags: linux, ubuntu, hard-drive

I tried the solution given [here](https://superuser.com/questions/40450/how-does-one-change-users-home-directory-in-ubuntu-9-04), however it did not help.

I am running Ubuntu from a USB flash drive, and have a usable hard drive in the computer I am constantly working on. I want the home directory and installed software to reside on the hard drive. How do I do that?

Comment: In what way did the other solution not help? The command given will change your home directory.

Comment: *it did not help*, why?

Comment: i ran the command - and nothing happened

Answer (score 1):

You are probably running a [non-peristent](http://www.pendrivelinux.com/what-is-persistent-linux/) Linux version on the USB stick. If so, you cannot make any changes to the system so even though the command you tried succesfully changed your `$HOME`, the changes are lost when you reboot.

The only way around this would be to create another USB drive with a [persistent system](http://www.howtogeek.com/65888/create-a-persistent-bootable-and-virtualized-linux-usb-drive-with-lili/).